# Accesing Data from Android

Tags: android, android-sqlite, adb

I have an Android application that I did develop. I used SQLite to store data locally. I have wanted to sync the data from the cloud to the local but this is taking too long. How can I access the data on the local before reinstalling the application and figuring a good option for syncing?

I am trying using ADB but I have been able to figure how it works with a CMD

Comment: You need to be clearer with what you're asking.  Are you asking how to get the db off the device?  If so, adb pull on the db file would work.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hello @Gabe Sechan Well. The application had some data transactions that I needed to recover before reinstalling the application. Since I could not sync to the cloud, I wanted to retrieve this data from the local db and manually input it into the system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your app is set to debuggable, you can check yours app files and download/upload in `Device Explorer` inside Android Studio.

Databases are stored in `/data/data/{app_package}/databases`